# How to read data from excel and concatenate columns vertically?

Tags: excel, pandas, concatenation

I'm reading this data from an excel file:

```
    a       b   
0   x   y   x   y
1   0   1   2   3
2   0   1   2   3
3   0   1   2   3
4   0   1   2   3
5   0   1   2   3
```

For each a and b categories (a.k.a samples), there two colums of x and y values. I want to convert this excel data into a dataframe that looks like this (concatenating vertically data from samples a and b):

```
    sample  x   y
0   a       0.0 1.0 
1   a       0.0 1.0 
2   a       0.0 1.0 
3   a       0.0 1.0 
4   a       0.0 1.0 
5   b       2.0 3.0
6   b       2.0 3.0
7   b       2.0 3.0
8   b       2.0 3.0
9   b       2.0 3.0
```

I've written the following code:

```
x=np.arange(0,4,2) # create a variable that allows to select even columns
    
sample_df=pd.DataFrame() # create an empty dataFrame

    
for i in x: # looping through the excel data 

    sample = pd.read_excel(xls2, usecols=[i,i], nrows=0, header=0)
    values_df= pd.read_excel(xls2, usecols=[i,i+1], nrows=5, header=1)
    
    values_df.insert(loc=0, column='sample', value=sample.columns[0])
    
    sample_df=pd.concat([sample_df, values_df], ignore_index=True)
    
display(sample_df)
```

But, this is the Output I obtain:

```
    sample  x   y   x.1 y.1
0   a       0.0 1.0 NaN NaN
1   a       0.0 1.0 NaN NaN
2   a       0.0 1.0 NaN NaN
3   a       0.0 1.0 NaN NaN
4   a       0.0 1.0 NaN NaN
5   b       NaN NaN 2.0 3.0
6   b       NaN NaN 2.0 3.0
7   b       NaN NaN 2.0 3.0
8   b       NaN NaN 2.0 3.0
9   b       NaN NaN 2.0 3.0
```

Comment: Read excel with option `header=[0,1]` and use `stack(level=0)`.

Comment: thank you @Quang Hoang. it works perfect. I also had to use ".sort_index(level=1)" to organize the data.
I tried doing this with 70 rows, and I got an this error message: "Passed header=[0,1] are too many rows for this multi_index of columns". Can you recommend a solution for this?